# Threads streaming

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

Introduction

I have a Server in Java that send video packets by packets in TCP to an Android Client.

In Android Client side, i have a class : DowloadVideo that receive packets of the Java Server and a Thread that launch the media player with the video.

Problem

My problem is that when i launch the video after 5s of receive packets, the media player read only the receipt packets at the moment when the media player launch.

Receive packets by the client continue..

But the media player can not read more of packets continues.

Code

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();



    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);


    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();


    Connexion connexion = new Connexion(list);
    connexion.execute();

    new Thread(new Task2(list)).start();



}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {


        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mediaPlayer.seekTo(1000);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });


}


private class Connexion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list;

    public Connexion(ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

        DownloadVideo dv = new DownloadVideo(list);
        dv.connexion();

        return null;
    }
}

public void launchVideo() {

    // Chemin de la vidéo


    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Movies/chrono2.mp4");
        Long max = file.length();


            vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
            vidHolder.addCallback(this);



    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
        //  displayToast(getResources().getString(R.string.error_unknownMX)); // Erreur, on affiche un message à l'utilisateur
        // Log.e( "Error", getResources().getString(R.string.error_unknownMX));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void displayToast(String message) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}




// Thread to read video
class Task2 implements Runnable {
    private ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list;

    public Task2(ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("1", "Thread2");
                launchVideo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: you seriously expect other people to spend their time to read through all of that code in order to find a bug in there; but you are not willing to spend a few more minutes in order to properly format all of the source code, so it is easier to read for others?! Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();

    vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);

    ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

    Connexion connexion = new Connexion(list);
    connexion.execute();

    new Thread(new Task2(list)).start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(vidAddress);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}


private class Connexion extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list;

    public Connexion(ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();

        DownloadVideo dv = new DownloadVideo(list);
        dv.connexion();

        return null;
    }
}

public void launchVideo() {
    vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
    vidHolder.addCallback(this);
}

// Thread to read video
class Task2 implements Runnable {
    private ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list;

    public Task2(ConcurrentLinkedDeque<OutputStream[]> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("1", "Thread2");
                launchVideo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```